# Simple OpenGL example crashes

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, glut, glew

I've just copy & pasted my first OpenGL project from a tutroial (yay!).
The code is super simple:

```
#include "freeglut.h"


void displayMe(void)
{
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  glutInit(&argc, argv);

  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE);
  glutInitWindowSize(300, 300);
  glutInitWindowPosition(500, 500);
  glutCreateWindow("Test");          /// CRASHES HERE!
  glutDisplayFunc(displayMe);
  glutMainLoop();

  return 0;
}
```

I use the latest versions of:

- Visual Studio (2017)
- Freeglut x86 (3.0.0)
- GLEW x86 (2.0.0)
- NVIDIA driver for my Geforce 1070

But my applicaion (built as x86) crashes immediately with the following exception:

> Exception thrown at 0x6907EE5F (nvoglv32.dll) in MyTest.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000250.

**EDIT:**
The crash occurs at this line:

> glutCreateWindow("Test");

**EDIT 2**
I just tried a different framework. Now I use GLFW instead of freeGLUT.
The application crashes, too, when creating the window :-(

```
#include <glfw3.h>

int main(void)
{
  GLFWwindow* window;

  /* Initialize the library */
  if (!glfwInit())
    return -1;

  /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
  window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL); // CRASH HERE
  if (!window)
  {
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
  }

  /* Make the window's context current */
  glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

  /* Loop until the user closes the window */
  while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
  {
    /* Render here */
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    /* Swap front and back buffers */
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);

    /* Poll for and process events */
    glfwPollEvents();
  }

  glfwTerminate();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: when you debug where does it go out? I guess `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` here.

Comment: Did you try to initialize GLEW with `glewInit()` after `glutCreateWindow`?

Comment: Could you try to run debugger on that code? At least you'll find out which function causes the crash.

Comment: Seconding the "Where's your `glewInit()` call?"  All those function pointers (like `glClear()` or `glFlush()`) declared by `glew.h` ain't gonna set themselves.

Comment: The example doesn't use any GLEW yet. So I guess there is no need for an glewInit()? I also added the line where it crashes to the post.

Comment: Doesn't crash for me.

Comment: @genpfault `glClear` and `glFlush` do not require GLEW (the acronym stands for "GL *extension* wrangler"). They are declared by `GL.h`, `glew.h` just redeclares everything.

Comment: And what's the stack trace? Use the debugger, Luke!